# ASP.Net Core 3.1 Error Load Azure Key Vault On Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, permission-denied, azure-keyvault

I Use ASP.Net Core 3.1 and I deploy it on Azure App Service (Web) On Linux.

the question is, when i deploy the code on Azure App Service, i got error message:

```
Unhandled exception. System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
        at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
        at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
        at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretsWithHttpMessagesAsync(String vaultBaseUrl, Nullable`1 maxresults, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretsAsync(IKeyVaultClient operations, String vaultBaseUrl, Nullable`1 maxresults, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync()
        at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()
        at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
        at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
        at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
        at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
        at ZHFSoftware.Program.Main(String[] args) in / home / runner / work / ZHFSoftware / ZHFSoftware / ZHFSoftware / Program.cs:line 19
        ptrace(ATTACH, 29) FAILED Operation not permitted
```

i know this is PERMISSION error related.
and when i run the web,

```
    :( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.
```

i can run the code in DEVELOPMENT and PRODUCTION, but on LOCALHOST (and i can get the azure key vault)
but NOT in the Deploy version. 
(https://.azurewebsites.net/) => Got Error

i already set the permission based on the manual :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-identity

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-integrate-azure-managed-service-identity?tabs=core2x

https://wakeupandcode.com/key-vault-for-asp-net-core-3-1-web-apps/

and i follow the youtube manual:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2VYcYS3EIA

but no use. still error.

Any help will appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: i already try this for 3 days. today i can have it run, by modify the KeyVault > Access Policy. but i try make it again from scratch. and BOOM. not running T.T

Comment: Based on the error `System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.`, I'd say check the parameters you are giving to Key Vault configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Today, i solved my problem.

i "Publish" my web project from Visual Studio 2019 Preview.
and Configure "Service Dependencies", and then Publish.

MY Website Running ...

i push to my github and found this item added.
"serviceDependencies. - Web Deploy.json"

and i open the file, it contains:

```
{
      "dependencies": {
        "secrets1": {
          "resourceId": "/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resGroudId>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<Key Vault Name>",
          "type": "secrets.keyVault",
          "connectionId": "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUP__KEYVAULT__CONFIGURATIONVAULT"
        }
      }
    }
```

NB: the Manual from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-github-actions-key-vault very useful. thanks Microsoft ^^/